# How to change the carousel active indicator color - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the carousel active indicator color. Here is the example

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/trybs_theme_band_full.htm#band

I want to change from white to red

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own yet?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Bootstrap style the controls the carousel active dot is `.carousel-indicators .active` so:

```
.carousel-indicators .active{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but with 2 dots in front of active, now it works. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can change the content of the control links by removing the SVG icon and changing it to a font-awesome icon. The icon can then be styled by adding a class to it. E.G.

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselProfileMedia" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x *YOUR-CUSTOM-CLASS*" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// CSS rule and invert the color, from black to white, using invert() .5 is gray

// we can use sepia() to turn our gray into a brown

// Using saturate() and hue-rotate(), we can fiddle with these values until we arrive at the desired color.

filter: invert(.5) sepia(1) saturate(5) hue-rotate(175deg);
```